# PowerPoint Macro - Paste Slides and Keep Source Formatting

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a core set of slides that I insert into all of my presentations saved on my desktop.  I wrote a macro that copies those slides and pastes them into the current open presentation but I lose the source formatting.  I read some other posts that do similar things but I can't seem to get the `ExecuteMso` command to work:

```
Sub insertSlides()
    
    Dim objPresentation As Presentation
    Dim currPresentation As Presentation
    Set currPresentation = Application.ActivePresentation
    
    Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\coreSlides.pptx", , False)
    objPresentation.Slides.Item(1).Copy
    currPresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    objPresentation.Close
    
 End Sub
```

Also, can you use this command to always paste a slide after slide 2?

Comment: Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768912/how-should-i-copy-and-paste-a-powerpoint-slide-keeping-source-formatting-with-vb), it seems like you are missing the navigating to destination presentation's slide part so try inserting `currPresentation.Windows(1).View.GotoSlide(2)` before you execute the command. @user3390169

Comment: "I have a core set of slides that I insert into all of my presentations" Simplify your life. Create a new template that already includes those slides and their layouts. Then you don't need copying or pasting or VBA.

Comment: @raymondwu that answer solves the problem of inserting at a certain slide, thank you!  But what about the formatting?  It still doesn’t seem to be following the original

Comment: @user3390169 I afraid I can't help you with that as I'm not familiar with PP VBA in the first place! But John's advice is right - if you have a set of slides that you need to use for all your presentations then you should make a template with those slides and the correct layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added one line to your code and it works great for me, and pasted the slide while keeping the original format.
`currPresentation.Windows.Item(1).Activate`

But the size of the slide is not saved, if you need it you can set it explicitly according to the size in the original presentation.

```
Sub insertSlides()
    
    Dim objPresentation As Presentation
    Dim currPresentation As Presentation
    Set currPresentation = Application.ActivePresentation
    
    Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("F:\1.pptx", , False)
    objPresentation.Slides.Item(1).Copy
    currPresentation.Windows.Item(1).Activate ' NEW LINE !
    currPresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    objPresentation.Close
    
 End Sub
```